# java if one thread run at a time why need synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

When multiple threads are running at the same time, why is there a need for synchronization in order to to avoid "problems" when accessing a shared resource?

I am new to both multi-threaded programming and synchronization concepts. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: One thread runs at one time but you cannot guarantee which will run when and also it does not mean that the one thread will complete its execution before other starts. Its interleaved. So synchronization is to avoid improper data read by other thread until on thread completes its function on it.

Comment: Also if we make any method synchronized, if 10 requests from different systems, if one request locks the method, other users will need to wait right?

Comment: [Google Java multi-thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). It shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Thanks thepace, polet.. do you mean that threads will run one by one but user appearance wise those are working concurrently...  am i right

Comment: @user1365766 - Not exactly. On Single processor systems that is indeed the case but not in systems with multiple cores. The use of syncronization is to make *changes* visible and keep *data consistnt*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this method:

```
private int value = 0;

public void computeStuff()
{
    int tmp = value;
    tmp++;
    value = tmp;
}
```

Suppose 1000 threads invoke this. Without synchronization, several threads can execute the computation in parallel, and it is uncertain whose outcome will be written to `value`. One thread's execution might be interrupted in between the assignment of `tmp` and the final assignment of `value`. The end result will be that `value` might not be equal to 1000 but possibly some lower value.

By adding `synchronize` to the method, all threads will invoke it one by one. Yes this will be slower than without `synchronize`, as some threads will be forced to wait for the pending lock. But the good news is that we're guaranteed the outcome will be `1000`.

(please note that I'm aware that this is a silly example - I like silly examples)